# Gson JsonParser.parseString() resulting in NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, maven, gson

I am using Gson's JsonParser.parseString(response) to convert a String response (which is in JSON format, validated manually) to JSON. This exact code is being refactored in from a different microservice, so I am certain that it works.

But the method throws NoSuchMethodError exception when the method is being called.

Maven dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

None of the methods I have tried have provided no improvement on the situation:

- I tried upgrading the dependency version to 2.10.1
- I tried adding the fully qualified name of the class, instead of importing it.
- I tried multiple maven cleans and installs.

Not sure what the underlying issue is.

Comment: Could you please try [the steps from the Gson Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#no-such-method-error) and report back if that helped or solved the issue?